# unresolved external symbol with diamond structure

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker, pure-virtual, diamond-problem

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class A1
{
public:
    virtual void a1() = 0;
};

class B1 : virtual public A1
{
public:
    virtual void b1()
    {
        A1::a1();
    }
};

class A1_Impl : virtual public A1
{
public:
    virtual void a1() {}
};

class B_Combined : virtual public A1_Impl/*, virtual public B1*/
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B_Combined b;
    return 0;
}
```

After removing `/*` and `*/` the compiler presents the `"'B_Combined': inherits 'A1_Impl::A1_Impl::a1' via dominance"` warning. I guess thats okay, because I want B_Combined to inherit the implementation of `A1::a1` in `A1_Impl` (its the only implementation).

But I also get an error message:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual void __thiscall A1::a1(void)" (?a1@A1@@UAEXXZ)".
```

I am a bit confused about this. Why doesn't the implementation in A1_Impl work? Deriving B_Combined from B1 should only add a new method `b1` calling the implementation of `A1::a1` in `A1_Impl`.

Comment: It works fine for me: http://ideone.com/817Pli

Comment: @user3369521 please show your real code, this compiles fine

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted compiles fine. However The linkage error that you mentioned will result from declaring

```
class B_Combined : virtual public A1_Impl, virtual public B1
{
};
```

for you do call `A1::a1();` in `virtual void B1::b1`, but `A1::a1` is pure abstract. You must not call `A1::a1` unless you provide a body for it.

Comment: Yes you are right, you have to remove the comment to see the problem. But I still do not get why the unresolved symbol is there. As you said I call A1::a1() which is not implemented in B1 but it is implemented in A1_Impl, doesn't this count?

Comment: no, classes B1 abd A1_impl doesn't share implementation. They both derive from A1 and they both has to implement virtual a1 if it is to be used. Moreover you can never call A1::a1() directly, because this is static call and function has no body

Comment: @user3369521 do you have additional questions?